# Why does this occur during windows boot and how can I solve it?

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, windows

[**Image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edz5P.png)

This is grub after I choose to boot windows. This issue doesn't cause any harm but it is annoying. It doesn't always occur every time I boot windows (always boots normally) and it never happened on booting ubuntu (kubuntu).

I'm booting in legacy mode, with screen resolution of 1920x1080, grub resolution is set to default and I have an NVIDIA card (quadro k3100m if it matters).

I have tried adding this in `/etc/grub.d/15_windows` (Probably not the best idea)

```
#!/bin/bash
exec tail -n +3 $0
# Be careful not to change the 'exec tail' line above.

menuentry "Windows 10" --class windows10 --class windows --class os {
        savedefault
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ntfs
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  <UUID>
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root <UUID>
        fi
    configfile /grub-cfg/windows.cfg
}
```

and `ntldr /bootmgr` to `/grub-cfg/windows.cfg` and it only took away that tearing, but still I can't boot to WINRE (and windows logo still doesn't always show) before I reboot twice in average which, fortunately, doesn't happen every day.

Comment: *I'm booting in legacy mode* Unless you have a BIOS machine that's a big mistake and the potential cause of many issues. With UEFI boot you would be able to boot Windows directly and troubleshoot from there. With BIOS/Legacy you can do the same ONLY if the OSes are installed in different drives and the dual-boot was set in a way that didn't remove the Windows bootloader from the other drive.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I have a bios/legacy machine and I can boot windows normally. My device shipped with win 7 preinstalled and has uefi capabilites, but converting to uefi require (AFAIK) a windows-only setup.

Comment: No, Ubuntu as well as all major distros have supported UEFI since a decade ago.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I mean I need to remove ubuntu, convert to uefi on the windows-only setup and then reinstall ubuntu.